# A\b or b\A for A*x=b in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, backslash

A solution of `A*x = b` can be obtained by `x = A\b`. But I did `x = b\A` as I did not look for exact syntax. I got different vectors `x` in with `A\b` and `b\A`. I understood that `A\b` is more or less equivalent to `inv(A)*b`, but I don't understand what exactly is happening if I do `b\A`. Does anyone know about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MATLAB documentation:

> If A is a rectangular m-by-n matrix with m ~= n, and B is a matrix with m rows, then A\B returns a least-squares solution to the system of equations A*x= B.

Comment: Hi Robbie, thanks for your answer. I got a clue from it. Here is what I understood. As A\b is the solution to A*x = b, where A is a matrix of any order, b\A is the solution to b*x = A. I observed that MATLAB calculates pseudo-inverse of b since b is a vector, in more general sense a n-by-1 matrix. I verified this by comparing pinv(b)*A with b\A. I was also able to see how pinv() gets the pseudo-inverse of vector b by setting symbolic elements  to vector b.

Comment: Great work, glad that you got to the bottom of it :)